# The correct way to dismiss a MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm at my wit's end.  I need to dismiss an `MFMailComposeViewController` when my app transitions to the background and I can't do it.  It ends up creating an awkward application state.

Is there a way to handle this programmatically?  Perhaps force the view controller to put the email into the Drafts folder and dismiss without animating?

EDIT:

Calls to `- dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` don't work as expected.

The awkward application state I'm talking about is my main view being redrawn over top of the email composer when the application returns from the background.  The modal is never dismissed and that email composer is never accessible again.

EDIT:

Code in my initializer:

```
// For compatibility with iOS versions below 4.0
if (&UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification != NULL)
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Code in my background-entry handler:

```
- (void) applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification:(NSNotification *)note {

  // Do some other stuff here

  // According to the docs, calling the method like this closes all
  //  child views presented modally
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details about what the "awkward application state" is?

Comment: Please show your `applicationDidEnterBackground` method. How are you trying to dismiss the composer at the moment?

Comment: I'm trying to use `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`, and I've tried calling it on the parent view controller (using `self`) and the email modal view itself.  Neither work.

Comment: And the above code is _in the viewcontroller that presents the composer_? I'm seeing why you're at your wit's end!

Comment: Yes, it is.  Even if it weren't, the current view stack is managed by any call to `- dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

Comment: I'm going to have a go at replicating this myself as it's a great problem (not so great for you, obviously) but I wonder if you are running out of time doing your "other stuff" - the docs do state you only get a short window to execute logic after the app has entered the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced a simple application with the code you have above. The mail composer is dismissed properly when the application enters the background.

I can only assume therefore that the `//Do some other stuff here` section of your code is doing too much stuff and the OS is shutting you down before you have chance to dismiss the composer.

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> You should perform any tasks relating to adjusting your user interface before this method exits but other tasks (such as saving state) should be moved to a concurrent dispatch queue or secondary thread as needed. Because it's likely any background tasks you start in applicationDidEnterBackground: will not run until after that method exits, you should request additional background execution time before starting those tasks. In other words, first call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and then run the task on a dispatch queue or secondary thread.

Perhaps you should move your other stuff to a different thread or request extra time? If you remove the other stuff, does the composer dismiss correctly?

Comment: Right, this did it.  It wasn't clean really, but keeping the UI work in the main thread and requesting some extra background time helped.